# Publishing the website to the server SQL Server 2008 R2 Error

Tags: asp.net

I have website in my local disk( E:) ,copied from my colleague. It is running fine when I restore the database in SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

I am running my website directly from E:,Now I want to set this website in  the server and make it online by setting the url path ad all. So I copied the database in the server and restored it in the server. I am not sure how to do the next steps
Now I have to copy the website to E: of the server. Then I am confused.

As I am new to this ,help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .net Publish function (Build menu) to copy the files for the site to a disk location or ftp address.

Comment: Sorry,From local host, i can publish to server...?Only thing I have done in the server is database restore.I am connecting the server through remote desktop

Comment: Do I need to do any changes in the server..?I mean in IIS

Comment: You'll need to set up a site with IIS and specify the folder the site files are in. If IIS is used for FTP, then you'll need to set the properties on the folder for that.

Comment: Alternatively, tnstead of FTP, you can publish to a local folder, then copy and paste to the remote desktop folder.

Comment: In iis I created a websie .can I publish from the local host(E:) to this website(IIS)(in the server) through remote connection.I have the public ip with me.

Comment: Yes. You will need to make sure ftp is enabled on the site, and that the folder has proper permissions.

Comment: FOR THIS PURPOSE , form E : For publishing website to IIS IN THE SERVER ,which option should I select FTP OR REMOTE SITE..?

Comment: In local host and server VS 2008 IS USING.BUT I can not load the project in server.the project file cannot be loaded msg is coming